# Add System Environment Windows Variable using command line

Tags: mysql, path, system, environment

I'm doing an unattended MySQL installer, with root password and all, everything goes fine!, now I'm on the final step.
I'm adding the System Environment Variable, in order to Add to "PATH" the path of where MySQL its installed, so I'm doing This:

```
setx PATH "C:\mysql\bin" /M
```

And it works, If you test in a command line I can invoke MySQL from any command line window.

But I realized that all the paths stored from other programs previously stored like "Java" and other ones were disappeared, and only Its saved the path of MySQL.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, because It must store all program Paths.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran this:

```
setx PATH "C:\mysql\bin" /M
```

Your overwrote (i.e. clobbered) whatever things you had in your previous `PATH` environment variable.  Instead, to *append* MySQL to your path use the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\mysql\bin
```

However, I usually update the PATH using the Windows GUI interface.  To do that you can open a dialog which contains the various environment variables.  There, you will see the literal value for the PATH and it should be straightforward to see how to append MySQL to end.  Checkout the following Server Fault question if you need more help doing this from the GUI:

https://serverfault.com/questions/465924/windows-how-do-i-add-a-program-to-the-systems-path-environmental-variable-from